# Create a function generateString(char, val) that returns a string with val number of char characters concatenated together

Tags: python

I have been working this for days and I can only come up with:

```
def generateString(char, val):
```

Comment: I know I need to do like.   return random but I'm not sure what will come after the above code

Comment: Surely you have done more than type that one line in your days of work. Why don't you show your best effort?

Comment: "return random"? Why random? Maybe you should clarify the question a little bit?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please explain exactly what this function should so.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, this should work if char is a string and val is an integer.

```
def generateString(char, val):
    return char * val
```

Comment: I tried that and the other part of the question had: For example generateString('a', 7) will return aaaaaaa. It sounds easy and I thought those two lines would be all I would need. Since this is supposed to be a random string.

Comment: So I figured it out today. I realized that I did not define the problem I needed and was just printing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

i did this

```py
import sys
import random
character= sys.argv[1]
count= int(sys.argv[2])

# Your code goes here
def generateString(char, count):
  random = char * count
  return random
print(character*count)
```

Program Output

```
Input: s 3
Your Output: sss
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just print(character * count) of course you will get the right output but the goal is to create an operational function and then output by using the function

```
import sys
character= sys.argv[1]
count= int(sys.argv[2])


def generateString(char, val):
   string = char * val
   return string

print(generateString(character, count))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this code to work:

```
# Get our arguments from the command line
import sys
character= sys.argv[1]
count= int(sys.argv[2])

# Your code goes here

def generateString(char, val):
  return char * val

print (generateString('s',3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without just printing the answer, this is what worked for me:

```
# Get our arguments from the command line
import sys
character= sys.argv[1]
count= int(sys.argv[2])

# Your code goes here
def generateString(char, val):
  str = print(char * val)
  return str
generateString(character, count)
```